# Java: check if two arrays contain the same element without any import

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a method which can check if two arrays are the same (without using any imports). Order does not matter and it can contain duplicates and the two arrays need to remain the same! My idea was to copy both of the arrays, then compare these two copy arrays. And if I find a valid equal pair, set to null that item in both of the copy arrays, so it can handle the duplications. So if both of the copy arrays have just null in them, the two array have the same element My problem is sometimes it works properly, so it finds the equal pairs, but sometimes it misses... I will send the log as well, it shows everything:

My code:

Solution.java:

```
public class Solution {

    public static boolean areTheyTheSame(int[] a, int[] b)
    {

        if (a.length == b.length)
        {

            //fill the copy arrays with the elements of a and b
            Integer copy_a[] = new Integer[a.length];
            Integer copy_b[] = new Integer[b.length];

            for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
            {
                copy_a[i] = a[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++)
            {
                copy_b[i] = b[i];
            }



            //check if the copy_a array and the copy_b array are the same

            for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0 ; j < b.length ; j++)
                {

                    System.out.println("... Comparing copy_a[" + i + "]=" + copy_a[i] + " with copy_b[" + j + "]=" + copy_b[j] + ":");




                    if ((copy_a[i] == copy_b[j]) && copy_a[i] != null && copy_b[j] != null)
                    {

                        System.out.println("Ohh,I found something. copy_a[" + i + "]=" + copy_a[i] + " equals copy_b[" + j + "]=" + copy_b[j] + ":");

                        copy_a[i] = null;
                        copy_b[j] = null;

                        System.out.println("What the arrays contain: ");


                        for (int k = 0 ; k < a.length; k++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("copy_a[" + k + "] = " + copy_a[k]);

                        }

                        System.out.println("--------------------------");

                        for (int k = 0 ; k < b.length ; k++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("copy_b[" + k + "] = " + copy_b[k]);
                        }


                    }




                }
            }

            //check if the copy array's all elements are null

            for (int i = 0 ; i < copy_a.length ; i++)
            {
                if (copy_a[i] != null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }



            return true;



        }
        else 
        {
            return false; // if a.length != b.length
        }

    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = new int[]{121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
        int[] b = new int[]{121, 19, 19, 144, 161, 144, 19, 11};


        if (Solution.areTheyTheSame(a, b) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Equal");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not equal");
        }


    }

}
```

My log:

```
... Comparing copy_a[0]=121 with copy_b[0]=121:
Ohh,I found something. copy_a[0]=121 equals copy_b[0]=121:
What the arrays contain: 
copy_a[0] = null
copy_a[1] = 144
copy_a[2] = 19
copy_a[3] = 161
copy_a[4] = 19
copy_a[5] = 144
copy_a[6] = 19
copy_a[7] = 11
--------------------------
copy_b[0] = null
copy_b[1] = 19
copy_b[2] = 19
copy_b[3] = 144
copy_b[4] = 161
copy_b[5] = 144
copy_b[6] = 19
copy_b[7] = 11
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[1]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[2]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[0]=null with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[1]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[2]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[1]=144 with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=19 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=19 with copy_b[1]=19:
Ohh,I found something. copy_a[2]=19 equals copy_b[1]=19:
What the arrays contain: 
copy_a[0] = null
copy_a[1] = 144
copy_a[2] = null
copy_a[3] = 161
copy_a[4] = 19
copy_a[5] = 144
copy_a[6] = 19
copy_a[7] = 11
--------------------------
copy_b[0] = null
copy_b[1] = null
copy_b[2] = 19
copy_b[3] = 144
copy_b[4] = 161
copy_b[5] = 144
copy_b[6] = 19
copy_b[7] = 11
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[2]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[2]=null with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[1]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[2]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[3]=161 with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=19 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=19 with copy_b[1]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=19 with copy_b[2]=19:
Ohh,I found something. copy_a[4]=19 equals copy_b[2]=19:
What the arrays contain: 
copy_a[0] = null
copy_a[1] = 144
copy_a[2] = null
copy_a[3] = 161
copy_a[4] = null
copy_a[5] = 144
copy_a[6] = 19
copy_a[7] = 11
--------------------------
copy_b[0] = null
copy_b[1] = null
copy_b[2] = null
copy_b[3] = 144
copy_b[4] = 161
copy_b[5] = 144
copy_b[6] = 19
copy_b[7] = 11
... Comparing copy_a[4]=null with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=null with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=null with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=null with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[4]=null with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[1]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[2]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[6]=19:
... Comparing copy_a[5]=144 with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[1]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[2]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[6]=19 with copy_b[6]=19:
Ohh,I found something. copy_a[6]=19 equals copy_b[6]=19:
What the arrays contain: 
copy_a[0] = null
copy_a[1] = 144
copy_a[2] = null
copy_a[3] = 161
copy_a[4] = null
copy_a[5] = 144
copy_a[6] = null
copy_a[7] = 11
--------------------------
copy_b[0] = null
copy_b[1] = null
copy_b[2] = null
copy_b[3] = 144
copy_b[4] = 161
copy_b[5] = 144
copy_b[6] = null
copy_b[7] = 11
... Comparing copy_a[6]=null with copy_b[7]=11:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[0]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[1]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[2]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[3]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[4]=161:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[5]=144:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[6]=null:
... Comparing copy_a[7]=11 with copy_b[7]=11:
Ohh,I found something. copy_a[7]=11 equals copy_b[7]=11:
What the arrays contain: 
copy_a[0] = null
copy_a[1] = 144
copy_a[2] = null
copy_a[3] = 161
copy_a[4] = null
copy_a[5] = 144
copy_a[6] = null
copy_a[7] = null
--------------------------
copy_b[0] = null
copy_b[1] = null
copy_b[2] = null
copy_b[3] = 144
copy_b[4] = 161
copy_b[5] = 144
copy_b[6] = null
copy_b[7] = null
Not equal
```

Comment: Why are you using `Integer[]` in your method when the inputs are `int[]`?

Comment: Assuming that it's OK to deep clone the two arrays, why don't you sort the cloned arrays, then compare item by item. Also do a preliminary test for equal length.

Comment: That is the only way to solve the problem without using imports, because Integers can be nulls but int cannot...

Comment: jarmond you are absolutaly right... I didnt think about that...

Answer (score 0):

sort the two copies of the arrays, and use just one for loop ( you do not need a nested loop), and inside this loop compare copy_a[i] and copy_b[i].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but seems from math perspective this can be checked by sum and product of arrays. Of course arrays must contain positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without imports:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

            int a[] = { 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 1 };
            int b[] = { 1, 6, 3, 4, 6, 2 };
            System.out.println(isEqual(sortingArray(a),sortingArray(b)));
        }   

    public static int[] sortingArray(int[] a) {

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = a[j + 1];
                        a[j + 1] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;

        }

        public static boolean isEqual(int[] first, int[] second) {
            if (first == second)
                return true;

            if (first == null || second == null)
                return false;

            if (first.length != second.length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
                if (first[i] != second[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You and most answers so far all seem to say 'check length first'.

This is incorrect; your own description of the problem states that duplicates do not matter, thus, array `[1, 1]` and array `[1]` are the same, and yet, do not have the same length. Thus proving that any length check of any sort is neccessarily incorrect.

Make 2 copies. Just `int[]`, not `Integer[]`, no need to mess with null here.

sort them both. Sorting is a fast (if complicated) operation. If you can't use `Arrays.sort`, time to google around for sorting algorithms, I guess.

now have a 'pointer' for each array, both starting at 0 of course. Your general operation is:

- Check the pointers; are they both at the end? Then the result is true: these contain the same.
- is one at the end and the other is not? Then false: These are not the same.
- check the current element in each. If not equal, then false: Not the same.
- Advance the pointers; not just by 1, but by however much is needed to hit a different element.

This in a loop will guarantee the correct result; the total performance is 2 sorts + 2 single-way though runs, which means the total runtime is 2x O(n) + 2x O(nlogn) for a total runtime of O(nlogn), which, I'm pretty sure is the theoretical fastest way to do this.

Comment: I don't think that's what he means by "may contain duplicates". It means that you might see [1,2,1]. It does not mean that [1,2,1] is equivalent to [1,2]. This is relevant because it means that a solution utilizing a set will not work.

Comment: if that's the case this is _much_ simpler, yup.